# How can I say that a chord (music) lasts for a period of time related to the rhythm of a song?

Tags: verbs, time

This is the first time I ask a question here and I hope someone can help me out. My question about English language is related to music, thus, although I can be wrong, I think it would be good to write about some musical concepts to help you to help me.
The conception of time in music is related to the way we feel the rhythm. We usually write music according to stressed and unstressed pulses, which causes a song to be divided in smaller parts called measures. Within the measures we have the strong and weak beats. Along with the rhythm, there are chords that are changed according to way the song was composed. Sometimes a chord can last for a whole measure, other times there are two or more chords that last small portions of the rhythm inside the measure. 
Suppose there are 2 chords within a measure of 4 beats. The first chord sounds from the first beat of the measure until the middle (or first half part)  of the second beat. Then other chord starts to be used from the middle of the second beat until the end of the measure as shown in the figure below:

[image: two chords per measure]

My question is: Is it wrong to say that the first chord lasts from the beginning of the measure until the middle of the second beat or would it be better to say that the first chord is used from the beginning of the measure until the middle of the second beat when the other chord will start to be used? I'm very confused about this. I'm not sure if I can say that the chord lasts, remains, is used for a part of the measure, or even sounds from the beginning until a given part of the measure. Could you help me please?

This is the real musical example:[image: bossa nova rhythm]

Best regards,
Renato.

Comment: Have you tried https://music.stackexchange.com? I think 'lasts' is fine, but all your suggestions seem similar, so there might not be an explicitly 'correct' form.

Comment: Hi Marcello, thank you for the tip. How can I mark your reply as helpful?

Comment: I think you have to have [a certain amount of reputation to vote](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). By the way, you notify people by @mentioning their name - they might not see the comment otherwise!

Comment: No problem, happy to help! You might want to check out the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) for more help about the site (and to get a badge!) and the [help centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: I would not say that the chord lasts.  The chord is repeated during that period.  To last it would need to be dotted quarter note (instead of the 3 eighth notes) or be tied.

Comment: @Jim Good point. But the example the figure shows is a simplified one. I'm teaching bossa nova guitar for beginners and I was looking for a way to explain the moment when the chord changes take place. When it comes to music written for guitar there are other elements to take into account. Maybe I have to change the image to one that represents the real situation. I've just used this one because I thought a real example would be difficult for non musicians to understand.

Comment: I would say "The chord changes on the *and* of two."

Comment: I have uploaded an image that shows the real musical example. Maybe you can help me a bit more. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. I think you could say the [same] chord is played/strummed during that period. Or if talking to a student “You’re playing the same chord until...” or “You’re on the same chord until...” “ Then you have a chord change.”

Comment: @jejorda2 Thank you. I've thought about this possibility. But I will record a video lesson about that and I was looking for the more detailed explanation I could get.

Comment: @Jim taking into account the last image I've uploaded, what do you think if I say in the following way?We start playing the rhythm on the pickup measure with the C6/9 chord. Next when we reach the "a" point of the first beat we have to change to the Fm6 chord. We keep playing the rhtyhm until reach the downbeat in the second measure when we have to change to the C6/9 chord. Then at the 2nd beat we have to change to the G7(13) chord. Finally, at the last eighth note we will change to the next chord shown in next measure.

Comment: *...until **reaching** the downbeat in the second* ...

Comment: @Jim Thank you for your patience on answering my questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think it is 'wrong' to say that

> 'the first chord *lasts* from the beginning of the measure *until* the middle of the second beat,'

and it's not necessarily better to say that

> the first chord *is used* from the beginning of the measure until the middle of the second beat'.

If anything, your second suggestion sounds more awkward to a native speaker.

English has many words that mean very similar things. There is rarely a right or wrong, unless you're a lawyer! Most differences are opinions, although some things sound better than others in some situations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm happy because I can communicate with people in English, something that I was not able to do 3 years ago. But master the subtleties of a second language takes a lifetime.